# Analytical calculation for focus deviation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, geometric-optics

How can I analytically calculate the deviation in focus or focal length variation in a situation as shown in figure. When the Sensor is parallel to the face of the lens/ light; its easy to calculate. How would I approach something like the 2nd case as shown in the figure.

Any ideas and advise would be great.

[image: 1]

Comment: You would approach it the same way as in the case with the properly adjusted focal plane, by analyzing the ray geometry. If you want to formalize this algebraically, instead of using geometry, there is a slew of ray transfer matrix techniques, which allow the calculation of general lens systems. See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_transfer_matrix_analysis for an introduction. By including higher order polynomial terms, these methods can also analyze the image formation and image defects that will arise from poorly adjusted optics.